# Android: Cursor issue and crashing app?

Tags: android, bootcompleted

I am trying to reset a bunch of date Notifications in a SQLite database after a device re-boot.  When I test, the app compiles but the Notifications don't fire and the app keeps crashing.

Code flow:

1) RebootReceiver attempts to capture the BOOT_COMPLETED event

2) RebootService is started to load all of the SQLite Notifications using a 
   cursor, PendingIntents and AlarmManager that will launch the AlarmReceiver.  The cursor uses the SQLite method "resetNotifications" to gather all of the dates (these are longs) from the Notification column in the database.

3) AlarmReceiver is a BroadcastReceiver to launch the AlarmService

4) AlarmService creates and shows the Notifications

What am I missing here?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<service android:name=".AlarmService"
        android:exported="false">
</service>
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.wimso.v095.intent.action.ALARM" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".RebootReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".RebootService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
```

RebootReceiver.java

```
...
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action == null) {
        return;
    }
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        intent.putExtra("TAG","bootCompleted");
    }        
    RebootService.enqueueWork(context, intent);
}
```

RebootService.java

```
public class RebootService extends JobIntentService {


// Unique job ID for this service
static final int JOB_ID = 10000;

public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
    enqueueWork(context, RebootService.class, JOB_ID, work);
}
@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {

    SQLiteDB sqLiteDB = SQLiteDB.getInstance(this);
    int randInt = 0;
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) {

        String classname = extras.getString("TAG");

        if (classname != null && classname.equals("bootCompleted")) {

            Intent brIntent1;
            AlarmManager alarmManager;
            PendingIntent pendingIntent1;

            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDB.resetNotifications();
            try {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst(); 

                    int notifColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_NOTIFTIME);
                    int randColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_RANDINT);

                    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { 

                        do {

                            long notifTime = cursor.getLong(notifColumnIndex);
                            randInt = cursor.getInt(randColumnIndex);

                            cal2.setTime(new Date(notifTime));

                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }

            // Set up a PendingIntent that will perform broadcast to the BroadcastReceiver.
            brIntent1 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            brIntent1.setAction("reBoot");   
            pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,randInt,brIntent1,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            int SDK_INT2 = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (SDK_INT2 >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(),
                            pendingIntent1);
                }
            } else if (SDK_INT2 >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {                    
                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
                }
            } else {                    
                if (alarmManager!= null) {
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
                }
            }
```

SQLiteDB.java

```
...
// Helps gather all Notifications so that after a device re-boot the Notifications can be reset.
public Cursor resetNotifications() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    if (db == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_NOTIFTIME};
        return db.query(
                TABLE_NAME, 
                columns, 
                null,      
                null,   
                null,   
                null,   
                null    
        );
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
...
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public AlarmReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action == null) {
        return;
    }
    else if (action.equals("reBoot")) {

        intent.putExtra("TAG","reBootReceiver");
    }

    AlarmService.enqueueWork(context, intent);
}
```

AlarmService.java

```
public class AlarmService extends JobIntentService {

    // Unique job ID for this service
    static final int JOB_ID = 9999;
    ...        
    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
        enqueueWork(context, AlarmService.class, JOB_ID, work);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {   
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) {
        String classname = extras.getString("TAG");
         else if (classname != null && classname.equals("reBootReceiver")) {

            // Send the Notification
            // The ID lets you update the notification later.
            int notify24HourID = 4;

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_announcement_white_24dp)
                            .setContentText("")                                
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
             if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.notify(notify24HourID, mBuilder.build());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your cursor iteration loop

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
    int notifColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_NOTIFTIME);
    int randColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_RANDINT);
    do {  
        long notifTime = cursor.getLong(notifColumnIndex);
        randInt = cursor.getInt(randColumnIndex);
        cal2.setTime(new Date(notifTime));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```